# Side-by-side divs overlapping as window width shrinks

Tags: css, responsive-design

**ANSWERED: I can't answer my own question for 8 hours.  The answer is below.**

I have figured out how to fix the issue I was having.  Here is the working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8fRTH/7/

First, instead of displaying the images as background images of each div, I placed them in img tags in each respective div.  I then applied max-width: 100%; to each image.

```
 /*----------------------------------------------------------
 *  Logo & Carousel strip
 *----------------------------------------------------------*/
#logo-bar {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo-bar div {
    margin: 0;
}

#logo-bar img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I added an overflow: hidden; to the main container to compensate for the fact that the #carousel image is larger than the height I would like by default for the #logo-bar container.

After that, I created a bit of Javascript to fire when the browser resizes to resize the #logo-bar container height to the height of the image in #logo-box.

```
$(window).resize(function(){     
    $('#logo-bar').height( $('#logo-box img').height() );
});
```

This makes the container height shrink at the same rate the browser naturally shrinks the logo by resizing the browser window, which in turn only displays the right amount of the image in the #carousel-box div.

Thanks to everyone who took time to look at this and offer help!

**ORIGINAL POST**

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

I have two divs that are side-by-side: #logo and #carousel.  #logo has a width of 33%, #carousel has a width of 66%.  When the browser is maximized, they are situated side-by-side, as intended.  However, as the browser window shrinks, the #carousel div begins to shift left and overlap the #logo div.

My expected result would be that since each div is a % of the total width, that as the browser window shrinks, each div would adjust accordingly.  This is not what is happening.  Additionally, if I leave the browser at a smaller size and reload the page, the right div still overlaps the left div.  I am not sure why they are having this behavior, as they should each be a set percentage of the total window size.

Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

**Edit #2:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/8fRTH/3/

I edited the JSFiddle to include images to demonstrate the problem.

**Edit:** Relevant code below:

```
<!--============================================
    Logo/Carousel Bar
================================================-->
    <div class="section group" id="logo-bar">
        <div class="col span_1_of_3" id="logo-box">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col span_2_of_3" id="carousel-box">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

/*----------------------------------------------------------
 *  Logo & Carousel strip
 *----------------------------------------------------------*/
#logo-bar {
    height: 300px;
}

#logo-bar div {
    margin: 0;
}

#logo-box {
    height: inherit;
    background-image: url("../img/raffa-logo.png");
    background-size: cover;
}

#carousel-box {
    height: inherit;
    background-image: url("../img/carousel-slide-1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

/*  SECTIONS  ============================================================================= */

.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  GROUPING  ============================================================================= */


.group:before,
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.group:after {
    clear:both;
}
.group {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   ==================================================================== */

.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; } /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */


/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col { 
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    }
}

/*  GRID OF THREE   ============================================================================= */


.span_3_of_3 {
    width: 100%; 
}

.span_2_of_3 {
    width: 66.13%; 
}

.span_1_of_3 {
    width: 32.26%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span_3_of_3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span_2_of_3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span_1_of_3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show some code please?

Comment: Jsfiddle would help as well.

Comment: I edited the original post to show all relevant HTML and CSS code.  I will put up a live preview shortly.  Thank you!

Comment: Okay.  I got a JSFiddle up, as well as a live version of the site with the problem in effect.  Thank you again for taking the time to try to help!

Comment: Can you just apply a "min-width" to the first div?

Comment: Hi Drew.  I added a min-width to the #logo div as a pixel size, which does stop the overlap.  However, it forces the #carousel div to the next line.  This also isn't optimal because I'd like both divs to stay on the same line, each taking their defined percentage, 33% and 66% respectively.  Setting a pixel min-width to the #logo div doesn't allow that div to scale with the browser window.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: The fiddle is working exactly as I would expect it to for a % width. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: If you look at the live site link below the fiddle, where background images are used, this is where you can witness the overlap.  I am not sure why when the divs have background images, the overlap seems to occur.

Comment: It's not an overlap. If you "inspect element", the elements are appropriately proportioned at 33 and 66%. The problem is that you haven't set the background images to resize with the divs

Comment: @JoelCornett I thought setting background-size: cover; would handle the images resizing with the div. What css attribute would you suggest to accomplish resizing the background image with the div?

Comment: Read the docs on `cover`, it stretches the background image to cover the element but it doesn't restrict the image to *only* fill the element.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, drop the `background-size: cover` and either fix the background width or height (but not both) at `100%`. This will ensure that the background image expands to the size of the element but does not overflow. In your case I believe you'd want to fix the width:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

## EDIT

works just fine here:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  When I tried that, it appears to still overlap.

Comment: @Joshwa.I.Am: Works just fine. See the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up.  I had a similar result when trying to implement your code, but upon resizing the window, the overlap still occurred.  The screenshot is unable to show whether that happens, but if you say you did and it worked, I believe you.